# In angular 2+ ui-router 1+, how do I pass parameters to child view?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Parent template

```
<ui-view [inputValue]="something"></ui-view>
```

Example child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '...'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() inputValue;
}
```

The UIView directive doesn't allow input parameters it doesn't know about (e.g. inputValue), so how could I get the "something" variable down to the child inputValue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property binding syntax and declare the inputValue as an attribute for the child selector block you used in Parent HTML block

Parent template

```
 <ui-view>
         <child inputValue="something"></child>
    </ui-view>
```

Example child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '...'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() inputValue;
}
```

Now you can use the inputValue in your child template